# iPad sized images in XCode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, image, ipad

I'm currently working on a universal iOS app.
But my iPad is taking the '@2x version' of each image.
I've read something about adding "~iPad" to the filename, this works perfect on the simulator but not on my (real) iPad.

Don't know what I'm doing wrong:

**iPhone (non-retina)**
image.png

**iPhone (retina)**
image@2x~iPhone.png *(this is the one that my iPad choses)*

**iPad (non-retina)**
image~iPad.png *(instead of this one)*

**iPad (retina)**
image@2x~iPad.png

Comment: Can you show us the code you're using to load/instantiate the `UIImage`?

Comment: [screenDisplay setBackgroundColor: [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background.png"]]];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Resource Programming Guide here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Introduction/Introduction.html

In the section titled *iOS Supports Device-Specific Resources* (emphasis mine):

> The 'device' string is a **case-sensitive** string that can be one of the following values:
>
> 1. ~ipad - The resource should be loaded on iPad devices only.
> 2. ~iphone - The resource should be loaded on iPhone or iPod touch devices only.

So instead of:

`image~iPad.png`

You should use:

`image~ipad.png`

Comment: Noticed that by myself a few seconds ago, but this doesn't help.
Still working on the simulator, not on the Device itself.

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned my build folder, re-added my images and now everything is working fine.

Here is to everyone with the same question a message:
As @Craig Otis mentioned, the difference between a capital and a non capital character is very important.
Watch this image to understand the image-naming:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18574780/2246164